# Julia millis() parameters?

Tags: julia

How do you get the current millisecond in Julia? In arduino C/C++, the millis() function is provided. I discovered that julia by default offers it too, it has a millis but it gives me an error of `MethodError: no method matching (::getfield(Main, Symbol("##7#8")))()` but it works by providing a certain parameter like `millis(0)` but I dont know what is that parameter. Documentation too is very poor in providing it.

Comment: Don't spam with irrelevant tags please. What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: cause I want to implement the millis alike function of python which uses lambda. Anyways, I think this question is wrong since I mistakenly assumed that millis is built-in in julia where infact it is not and im tricked by the repl..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using

```
millis = () -> (time() * 1000)
```

Comment: You don't have to write `Base.time()`, just `time()`.

Comment: It can be shorted even to `millis() = 1000time()`

Comment: If you want to avoid `Float64`, this somewhat ugly code produces the correct value:  `using Dates;now().instant.periods.value - DateTime(1970,1,1,1,0,0,0).instant.periods.value`. Any ideas to decrease ugliness?

Comment: It is dangerous to rely on internal fields of objects like that. But if you just write `now() - DateTime(1970,1,1,1,0,0,0)` it will return a `Millisecond` object, and will actually print the time in milliseconds. `t.value` then contains the number of milliseconds as an `Int64`. Not sure if there is some other way to access that value.

Comment: @DNF there is: `Dates.value(now() - DateTime(1970,1,1,1,0,0,0))` now it looks better :-)

Comment: And most elegant would be `Dates.value(now()) - Dates.UNIXEPOCH` which I think can be considered as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want `Float64` this looks nice

```
julia> using Dates

julia> Dates.value(now()) - Dates.UNIXEPOCH
1552950448955
```